# what is the relationship between birefringence and resonant interaction?

Tags: interaction

In the Newport offical website, it says:

The interaction of light with the atoms or molecules of a material is wavelength dependent. A result of this dependence is the resonant interactions related to material dispersion. Birefringence is another consequence of such resonant interaction, which is the change in refractive index with the polarization of light.
[text](https://www.newport.com/n/introduction-to-waveplates)

I cannot figure out why the resonant interaction can result in birefringence.
Your help would be highly appreciated.

I read the theory of birefringence, it should use tensor and cannot find anything about resonant interactions.